# Problema al configurar URL "amigables" en WampServer

Tags: php, html, html5, .htaccess, wamp

He leído cantidad de paginas incluso muchas preguntas y respuestas hechas aquí en stackoverflow y con ninguna he podido solucionar este inconveniente.

Estoy tratando de convertir la url `wallpaper.php?t=abstracto` a `wallpaper/abstracto` por medio del archivo `.htaccess` pero no ha sido posible para mi.

Me encuentro modificando cosas de la pagina web por lo que estoy trabajando en localhost (no en el servidor-hosting), trabajo con WampServer y ya he activado *LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so* en el *httpd.conf* de Apache.

**Mi archivo .htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# AL TENER ESTAS DOS OPCIONES ACTIVAS TAMPOCO FUNCIONA
#RewriteBase /wallpplus/
#RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^wallpaper/(.*)$ wallpaper.php?t=$1 [L]

# ESTA PARTE REDIRIGE HTTP A HTTPS Y DE WWW. A /
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !wc-api [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wallpplus.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.wallpplus.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://wallpplus.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

El href lo estoy haciendo asi `href="wallpaper/abstracto"`

Pero al hacer clic en el, WampServer me da el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deduzco que se debe a que en el archivo `wallpaper.php` estoy imprimiendo la variable `t` que debería llegar por medio de `$_GET['t']`

Sin embargo les comparto lo que tengo hasta el momento en el archivo `wallpaper.php`

```
<?php

echo $_GET["t"];

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar tu línea:

```
RewriteRule ^wallpaper/(.*)$ wallpaper.php?t=$1 [L]
```

Por la siguiente incluyendo el .php:

```
RewriteRule ^wallpaper.php/(.*)$ wallpaper.php?t=$1 [L]
```

Con eso te debería funcionar